# Alter columns primary key and foreign key VARCHAR datatype to INT datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key, sqldatatypes, alter-table

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.
I have 2 tables that contain data.

- `Area` table has **varchar** primary key
- `PersonalData` table references `Area` table using **varchar** foreign key

How can I change a `varchar` primary key and foreign key to `int` datatype?

SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z.Tests.Area]
(
    [ID_Area] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](150) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Z.Tests.Area] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Area] ASC) 
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z.Tests.PersonalData]
(
    [ID_PersonalData] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FK_ID_Area] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Z.Tests.PersonalData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_PersonalData] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Z.Tests.PersonalData] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Z.Tests.PersonalData_Z.Tests.Area] 
    FOREIGN KEY([FK_ID_Area])
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Z.Tests.Area] ([ID_Area])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Z.Tests.PersonalData] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Z.Tests.PersonalData_Z.Tests.Area]
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a multi-step process:

1. Check that the data is clean and convertible to `int`
2. Drop the foreign key constraint and any indexes on `FK_ID_Area`
3. Drop the primary key constraint and any indexes on `ID_Area`
4. `ALTER TABLE [Z.Tests.Area] ALTER COLUMN [ID_Area] int Not Null;`
5. `ALTER TABLE [Z.Tests.PersonalData] ALTER COLUMN [FK_ID_Area] int Null;`
6. Recreate primary key and indexes
7. Recreate foreign key and indexes

You'll definitely want to be careful here because there are potentially other things that could prevent this from working (schemabound views, check constraints etc).

Comment: Only thing I would add to this is that you should do these steps first in a test environment.  This way you know its highly likely to work in production.

Comment: ***Considers***: _Primary key, foreign key and unique key, and indexes_